# sharpPDF tables crops letters

Tags: c#, pdf

I'm using sharpPDF 1.3.1 (latest non-beta).

When creating a table with cellpadding < 3 the lower part of letters get cropped (i.e. q and g will look the same). Is there anyway to fix this?

Maybe by editing the src somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds very much like the padding is calculated from the baseline of the font (where the letter sits) rather than from any descender (the tail that protruded below the baseline, like on a 'y'). I've seen this in other PDF libraries, you can either specify a sufficient cellpadding or you could modify the source to either offer separate cellpadding values for top, left, right and bottom allowing you to specify a larger bottom cellpadding. You could also modify the source to add an extra 3px on the bottom to accommodate (not nice I suspect) or finally, query the font being used for the descender size and adjust the bottom padding accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

I centered the text in the cells vertically, this solved it for me.